# Why does Wikidata's query interface return no results for entities with an id of Q10000001 or higher?

Tags: wikidata, sparql

I have this SPARQL query to return an item's label and the url of a Wikipedia article:

```
PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/>
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
SELECT ?article ?itemLabel WHERE
    { FILTER ( ?item = wd:Q10000000 )
      ?article  schema:about       ?item ;
                schema:inLanguage  "en" ;
                schema:isPartOf    <https://en.wikipedia.org/> .

      SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
    }
```

This works as expected, but as soon as I substitute the id with `Q10000000` or any higher number included, it yields no result. Not only to the entities I checked exist, but also does the [query editor](https://query.wikidata.org/#PREFIX%20schema%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20wd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2F%3E%0ASELECT%20%3Farticle%20%3FitemLabel%20WHERE%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20FILTER%20(%20%3Fitem%20%3D%20wd%3AQ10000000%20)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Farticle%20%20schema%3Aabout%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20schema%3AinLanguage%20%20%22en%22%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20schema%3AisPartOf%20%20%20%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2F%3E%20.%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%20%7D%0A%7D%0A) display a label when hovering over the id in that expression.

What is causing this behaviour and how can I adjust the query to get results for entities with ids that have an id of Q10000001 and higher?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There [isn't](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q10000001#sitelinks-wikipedia) an article about [Татьяна Колотильщикова](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0,_%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0) in English Wikipedia.

Just [comment out](https://query.wikidata.org/#PREFIX%20schema%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20wd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2F%3E%0ASELECT%20%3Farticle%20%3FitemLabel%20WHERE%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20FILTER%20%28%20%3Fitem%20%3D%20wd%3AQ10000001%20%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Farticle%20%20schema%3Aabout%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20schema%3AinLanguage%20%20%22en%22%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20schema%3AisPartOf%20%20%20%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2F%3E%20.%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%20%7D%0A%7D%0A) the second and the third triple patterns in your query.

Or try e. g. [`Q11000001`](http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q11000001) instead of `Q10000001`.

Comment: funny thing is that i ended with that apparent cut-off value with trying some ids between my initial problem (without an article) and 10000000.

Comment: @funky-future, `wd:Q10000017` seems to be the nearest one.